# Where can I find the package org.omg.CosTransactions

Tags: java, interface, package, corba

i had the problem that i downloaded the JTS package from oracle's java page but it contains an old version of the JTS/OTS which doesn't seem to support the Current interface.

i have been told to download java EE and install it. actually it is installed now but i can't find org.omg.CosTransaction.* anywhere  and it is not possible to import it in eclipse because ecilpse doesn't find it ... except of the old JTS package which would work but ... yes
no Current interface.

greetings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/omg/CosTransactions/Current.html) to find jar of your needs.